# Android - CirclePageIndicator with custom drawable

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using CirclePagerIndicator https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator but I need to customize whole paint object with an image resource. One for selected page and another for not selected state. Now this library can only accept color. Is there a way or alternative to do that?

this is what I'm trying to do:

```
final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
circlePageIndicator.setStrokeWidth(2);
circlePageIndicator.setStrokeColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); //<== need resource image here not color
circlePageIndicator.setRadius(6 * density);
```

thanks.

***EDIT***

Since I have not found any solution around I decided to create my own library to do that, inspirated to Jake Wharton CirclePageIndicator. I post a link that should help all those who need it:

https://github.com/augustopicciani/DrawablePageIndicator

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the [style.xml file at the original source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml), it will show you customizable attributes.

To customize styles, apply attributes at the layout xml file as below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHeaderBanner"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/circlePageIndicator"
        app:fillColor="#56b8e9"
        app:pageColor="#d2d2d2"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:centered="true"
        app:strokeWidth="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` is defined in order to utilize attributes at the `styles.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that but I need to set @drawable/my_icon in fillColor and in pageColor. Can't use Color because the icon is a bit complex and it should have different stroke between state Selected and non Selected.

Comment: @AugustoPicciani // that could be pain. you may require to define your own drawable attributes.

Comment: ok, there's a way to set stroke programmatically from code that change when state is selected and when state is unselected?